# Error: Manually adding the rootViewController's view to the view hierarchy is no longer supported

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I upgraded to Xcode 11.1 and trying to compile an older Objective C app that programmatically sets the `rootViewController`.

How do I work around this error?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];

    nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the line `[self.window addSubview:nav.view];`? Delete it. It was always wrong.

Comment: Where "always" means "since iOS 4.0".

Comment: @rmaddy Which is pretty much where I came in. :) I did start writing for iOS 3.2 but it got unified with the iPad into iOS 4 before I got very far.